# CSS variables in media queries on Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

Does Chrome not support CSS variables within media queries?

I have the following CSS:

```
:root {
 --threshold-lg: 1200px;
 --threshold-md: 992px;
 --threshold-sm: 768px;
 --sidebar-margins: 10px;
}

@media(min-width: var(--threshold-sm)) {
  .sidebar {
    top: var(--sidebar-margins);
    bottom: var(--sidebar-margins);
  }
}
```

In both Chrome 50 and Chrome Canary (52), I see no margin adjustment. In Safari 9.1, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly CSS variables cannot be used in @media queries.  For more details see the top answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries).  (I would flag these two questions as duplicates if I knew how and had access!)

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
 --threshold-lg: 1200px;
 --threshold-md: 992px;
 --threshold-sm: 768px;
 --sidebar-margins: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}
@media(min-width: 300px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--sidebar-margins);
    bottom: var(--sidebar-margins);
    background-color: tan;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
```

Based on this test it seems it is only the media query conditional that has the issue.