# CSS native variables not working in media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, css-variables

I am trying to use CSS variables in media query and it does not work.

```
:root {
  --mobile-breakpoint: 642px;
}

@media (max-width: var(--mobile-breakpoint)) {

}
```

Comment: Just to clarify for people finding this through Google: you *can* use CSS custom properties inside the scope of a media query, you just cannot use them in a media query declaration.

Comment: Imagine if you changed `--mobile-breakpoint` inside of the media query's `:root`. That would be a recursive glitch I think

Answer (score 276, accepted):

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables),

> The `var()` function can be used in place of any part of a value in
>   any property on an element. The `var()` function can not be used as
>   property names, selectors, or anything else besides property values.
>   (Doing so usually produces invalid syntax, or else a value whose
>   meaning has no connection to the variable.)

So no, you can't use it in a media query.

And that makes sense. Because you can set `--mobile-breakpoint` e.g. to `:root`, that is, the `<html>` element, and from there be inherited to other elements. But a media query is not an element, it does not inherit from `<html>`, so it can't work.

This is not what CSS variables are trying to accomplish. You can use a CSS preprocessor instead.

Comment: The answer is correct in that the spec doesn't currently handle CSS variables in media queries, but incorrect in that is not what CSS variables are trying to accomplish. **Reducing repetition and magic numbers is exactly why CSS variables were created** -- see https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#intro

Comment: BTW how is this *NOT* a property value ?? It's `max-width`'s property value! It should totally work!

Comment: @user9645 Actually, no. It may _look_ like the `max-width` property because you write the same text, but it accomplishes something completely different. A CSS property declaration acts as a "setter", it sets a value for an element, while the `max-width` in a media query is a "getter": it requests the current width of something (and then compares it to the value provided). The text `max-width: 1000px` as a media query is (in the form of some NON-VALID pseudocode) something like `viewport.getWidth() <= 1000px`, while as a property declaration it would be `element.setMaxWidth(1000px)`.

Comment: any updates for 2023?

Answer (score 143):

As [Oriol has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723269/644104), [CSS Variables Level 1’s `var()` cannot currently be used in media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables). However, there have been recent developments that will address this problem. **Once [CSS Environment Variables Module Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-env-1/) is standardized and implemented, we’ll be able to use `env()` variables in media queries in all modern browsers.**

The CSS Working Group (CSSWG) codified `env()` in a new standard (currently at a draft stage): the **[CSS Environment Variables Module Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-env-1/)** (see [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693#issuecomment-385120028) and [this comment](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/pull/1817#issuecomment-385120102) for more info). The draft calls out variables in media queries as an explicit use case:

> Because environment variables don’t depend on the value of anything drawn from a particular element, they can be used in places where there is no obvious element to draw from, such as in `@media` rules, where the `var()` function would not be valid.

If you read the specification and have a concern, or if you want to voice your support for the media-query use case, you can do so in [issue #2627](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2627), in [issue #3578](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3578), or in [any CSS GitHub issue labeled with “css-env-1”](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues?q=label%3Acss-env-1+sort%3Aupdated-desc).

[GitHub issue #2627](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2627) and [GitHub issue #3578](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3578) are devoted to custom environmental variables in media queries.

---

Original answer from 2017-11-09:
Recently, the [CSS Working Group decided](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693#issuecomment-330909067) that **CSS Variables Level 2 will support user-defined environment variables using `env()`, and they will try to make them be valid in media queries**. The Group resolved this [after Apple first proposed standard user-agent properties](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693), shortly before the official announcement of iPhone X in September 2017 (see also [WebKit: “Designing Websites for iPhone X” by Timothy Horton](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/)). Other browser representatives then agreed they would be generally useful across many devices, such as television displays and ink printing with bleed edges. (`env()` used to be called `constant()`, but that has now been deprecated. You might still see articles that refer to the old name, such as [this article by Peter-Paul Koch](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2017/10/safeareainset_v.html).) After some weeks passed, [Cameron McCormack of Mozilla realized](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693#issuecomment-320822972) that these environment variables would be usable in media queries, and [Tab Atkins, Jr. of Google then realized](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693#issuecomment-321024740) that user-defined environment variables would be especially useful as global, non-overridable root variables usable in media queries. Now, [Dean “Dino” Jackson of Apple will join Atkins](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693#issuecomment-330909067) in editing Level 2.

You can subscribe to updates on this matter in [**`w3c/csswg-drafts` GitHub issue #1693**](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693) (for especially relevant historical details, expand the meeting logs embedded in the [CSSWG Meeting Bot’s resolutions](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693#issuecomment-330909067) and search for “MQ”, which stands for “media queries”).

Answer (score 120):

What you ***can*** do however is @media query your `:root` statement!

```
:root {
     /* desktop vars */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    :root {
        /* mobile vars */
    }
}
```

Totally works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge at least the latest production versions as of this posting.

One limitation: if you need to access the value as a variable – for example to use in calculations elsewhere – you will need to have a variable, and it requires defining the variable in two places: the media query and variable declaration.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you suggest? this means no support right?

Comment: @windmaomao browsers do not support CSS vars in the media rule, but they do support the technique shown in this answer, which is to declare vars in media rule. I guess what this answer isn't showing is actually using a var. You could (for example) declare different values for `--text-size` in each `:root` in the answer and then later do something like `h1 { font-size: var(--text-size) }` and it'll use the appropriate value.

Comment: Oh, that is PRO. That is just brilliant. Thank you @Sean.

Answer (score 36):

Apparently it's just not possible to use native CSS variables like that. It's one of the [limitations](https://hospodarets.com/css_properties_in_depth).

A clever way to use it is to change your variables in the media-query, to impact all your style. I recommend [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/css-variables-why-should-you-care).

```
:root {
  --gutter: 4px;
}

section {
  margin: var(--gutter);
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  :root {
    --gutter: 16px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "change your variables in the media-query", you can show example?

Comment: Yes, just did, it's in the article I linked. I know it's not what you expected, but CSS variables **just can't be used to define the media queries**

Comment: This is important. Imagine using the custom property's value in the @media rule - and then also wanting to change the value of that custom property - at that same break-point. it's weird... but they are custom properties  - and not just variables. So, - it seems like the reason it wasn't created that way - is better explained with an example than the spec. A combo would be best.

Answer (score 24):

The [level 5 specification of media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-5/#custom-mq) define *Custom Media Queries* that does almost what you are looking for. It allows you to define breakpoint similar to how you do with CSS variables and later use them in different places.

Example from the specification:

```css
@custom-media --narrow-window (max-width: 30em);

@media (--narrow-window) {
  /* narrow window styles */
}
@media (--narrow-window) and (script) {
  /* special styles for when script is allowed */
}
```

There is still no support for this actually so we have to wait before using this feature.

Answer (score 18):

One way to achieve what you want is using npm package `postcss-media-variables`.

If you are fine with using npm packages then you can take a look documentation for same here:

- [postcss-media-variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-media-variables)

Example

```
/* input */
:root {
  --min-width: 1000px;
  --smallscreen: 480px;
}
@media (min-width: var(--min-width)) {}
@media (max-width: calc(var(--min-width) - 1px)) {}

@custom-media --small-device (max-width: var(--smallscreen));
@media (--small-device) {}
```

Comment: et. al : With postcss you can also use cssnext http://cssnext.io/features/#custom-media-queries

Comment: @sebilasse: [custom-media-queries](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-media) does not address the main problem of not being able to use css variables as breakpoints for media queries

Answer (score 9):

### Short Answer

You can use JavaScript to change the value of media queries and set it to the value of a css variable.

```js
// get value of css variable
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--mobile-breakpoint'); // '642px'

// search for media rule
var mediaRule = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j];

// update media rule
mediaRule.media.mediaText = '..'
```

### Long Answer

I wrote a small script which you can include on your page. It replaces every media rule with a value of `1px` with the value of the css variable `--replace-media-1px`, rules with value `2px` with `--replace-media-2px` and so on. This works for the media queries `with`, `min-width`, `max-width`, `height`, `min-height` and `max-height` even when they are connected using `and`.

**JavaScript:**

```js
function* visitCssRule(cssRule) {
    // visit imported stylesheet
    if (cssRule.type == cssRule.IMPORT_RULE)
        yield* visitStyleSheet(cssRule.styleSheet);

    // yield media rule
    if (cssRule.type == cssRule.MEDIA_RULE)
        yield cssRule;
}

function* visitStyleSheet(styleSheet) {
    try {
        // visit every rule in the stylesheet
        var cssRules = styleSheet.cssRules;
        for (var i = 0, cssRule; cssRule = cssRules[i]; i++)
            yield* visitCssRule(cssRule);
    } catch (ignored) {}
}

function* findAllMediaRules() {
    // visit all stylesheets
    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0, styleSheet; styleSheet = styleSheets[i]; i++)
        yield* visitStyleSheet(styleSheet);
}

// collect all media rules
const mediaRules = Array.from(findAllMediaRules());

// read replacement values
var style = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
var replacements = [];
for (var k = 1, value; value = style.getPropertyValue('--replace-media-' + k + 'px'); k++)
    replacements.push(value);

// update media rules
for (var i = 0, mediaRule; mediaRule = mediaRules[i]; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < replacements.length; k++) {
        var regex = RegExp('\\((width|min-width|max-width|height|min-height|max-height): ' + (k+1) + 'px\\)', 'g');
        var replacement = '($1: ' + replacements[k] + ')';
        mediaRule.media.mediaText = mediaRule.media.mediaText.replace(regex, replacement);
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```css
:root {
  --mobile-breakpoint: 642px;

  --replace-media-1px: var(--mobile-breakpoint);
  --replace-media-2px: ...;
}

@media (max-width: 1px) { /* replaced by 642px */
  ...
}

@media (max-width: 2px) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build a media query programmatically using [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```js
const mobile_breakpoint = "642px";
const media_query = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${mobile_breakpoint})`);
function toggle_mobile (e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    document.body.classList.add("mobile");
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove("mobile");
  }
}
// call the function immediately to set the initial value:
toggle_mobile(media_query);
// watch for changes to update the value:
media_query.addEventListener("change", toggle_mobile);
```

Then, instead of using a media query in your CSS file, apply the desired rules when `body` has the `mobile` class:

```css
.my-div {
  /* large screen rules */
}

.mobile .my-div {
  /* mobile screen rules */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can read other answers, still **not possible** to do so.

Someone mentioned custom environmental variables (similar to custom css variables **`env()`** instead of `var()`), and the principle is sound, though there are still 2 major issues:

- weak browser support
- so far there is no way to define them (but probably will be in the future, as this is so far only an unofficial draft)

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer to using variables in media queries, but it tackles the problem of having to specify the width multiple times in components

My solution uses container queries in combination with media queries and exploits the possibility to have named containers.

First we need to define the breakpoints

```
@media (min-width: 399px) {
  body {
    container-type: inline-size;
    container-name: xsmall;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1079px) {
  body {
    container-type: inline-size;
    container-name: xsmall small;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1439px) {
  body {
    container-type: inline-size;
    container-name: xsmall small medium;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1999px) {
  body {
    container-type: inline-size;
    container-name: xsmall small medium desktop;
  }
}
```

Here we use the possibility to define multiple container names on elements. Using the mobile first approach and adding styles as we go up in screen size.

Now if we want to make some changes to a element in the small screen size and up I can add this style definition

```
@container small (min-width: 0) {
  ... some css
}
```

IMO the only thing that makes this look hacky is that the container query need to have a predicate, so the (min-width:0) is needed to make it work.

With this approach we can specify screen breakpoints in a single place and and remove all absolute screen sizes queries from components.

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 5, I've solved this with the media-breakpoint-down() function.

First of all, you'll need to import the functions, variables, and mixins files:

```
@import "~/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

And then, include your specific media style:

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
.btn {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}}
@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}}
@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
.btn {
  display: none;
}}
```

Where Breakpoints are defined as a map of (name: minimum width), order from small to large: (xs: 0, sm: 576px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px, xxl: 1400px)

You can also use the media-breakpoint-up(), media-breakpoint-only(), media-breakpoint-between().

See the official doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#media-queries

Answer (score 0):

## How to use Variables for Media Query Break Points

So guys i tried something like this below but it wasn't working, so i found out that css variables does not work on break points so what i did was to use SCSS

```css
  @media only screen and (max-width: var(--bp-tablet)) {
    display: none;
  }
```

SCSS CODE

1. Create your variable for scss

```css
$bp-tablet: 56.25em; // 900px
```

2. call the variable in the breakpoints and that's it!

```css
media only screen and (max-width: $bp-tablet) {
    display: none;
  }
```