# Setting CSS `env()` variables programmatically using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Now that CSS supports not only custom properties but also [environment variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env) I would like to know how they can be changed programmatically using javascript.

From the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-env-1/#funcdef-env):

> Environment variables can be defined by the user agent, or by the user

The following example will render a text in `purple` color.
Is it possible to change it to another color e.g. after 5 seconds using a setTimeout?

```css
div {
  color: env(PRIMARY, purple)
}

@media (min-width: env(small-screen, 100px)) {
  div { 
   font-size: large;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```

Comment: Isn't the only reason it's turning the text `purple` because there is no `env` variable for `PRIMARY`, so it's relying on the fallback? From my understanding, custom `env` variables set by stylesheet authors isn't supported yet or at least there's no spec set on how it will be implemented. And, I believe this might not work as the purpose of `env` variables is to make them a static value.

Comment: Actually I would like to have a javascript controlled media query - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47212942/159319 explains that this will be possible with `env` and I was hoping that now that it is part of the browser it might already work

Comment: Ahh. Your question doesn't mention `media` queries. You might want to update the question to include that information - for future visitors. And still, browsers support a very limited set of `env` variables - the ones hard coded into the browser - as custom ones do not appear to be available yet. Once the spec is figured out for custom `env` vars, I think this will allow for some interesting functionality!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the variable in `:root` and then accessing that variable in `env` allows you to modify it via javascript.

```js
var obj = document.getElementById("test");
setTimeout(function(){
    obj.style.setProperty("--primary","black");
},2000);
```

```css
:root{
   color:env(--primary,red);
}

#test {
  color: var(--primary)
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it is not what I meant.
You are using `var` but I asked how you would do that for `env`

Comment: @jantimon, I updated my answer to be a combo of `var` and `env` and it still works.

Comment: But your code changes the `var` not the `env` value.
`var` values must not be used inside media queries

Comment: @jantimon did you find a way to achieve it ? 
I created a ticket on MDN: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/question-is-there-a-way-to-override-css-native-env-variable-like-safe-area-inset-top/79675

Answer (score -1):

The way I handle it is pretty simple: do not use env(), use var() instead. Environment variables are, as they are named, variables coming from the environment and there is not any way to change them.

BUT! You can easily use their value to set a variable's value, and you can then play with that variable however you want. So, as long as you have access to the CSS that will be using the environment variable, you can use the var() version. Here's a demo.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--primary","black");
},2000);
```

```css
:root{
   --primary: env(PRIMARY,purple);
   --secondary: env(SECONDARY,blue);
}

#test {
  color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 1px) {
  #test { 
   color: var(--primary);
  }
}

#test2 {
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Hello world</div>

<div id="test2">Hello world 2</div>
```

Comment: OP's somewhat old, but for some reason, I could not find a solution from Google and this was the first result.

Comment: it's the same code like above answer

Comment: No it is not. This uses the environment inside a variable, the other answer sets color in :root to the environment. That is very different, altough it LOOKS very similar.

Comment: Let's say you wanted to use the color for a background or a border, you could use the variable where needed, without having to apply the background-color to the whole document.

Comment: what makes `env` special is that it is allowed to be used within media queries - copying the value into a css variable and using a css variable is something different imho

Comment: Of course env and var are different, or else we only would have one of them :) One big difference is that their value comes from different scopes, ENV scope is not modifiable by the website, only by the browser. That's why I suggest to use a variable instead, but with a default value of the environment which covers perfectly OP's question IMO.