# Is it possible to use Sass variable within styled-component @media query?

Tags: reactjs, sass, styled-components

I have defined sass variable `$mobile`

```
$mobile: "(min-width: 320px) and (max-width:479px)";
```

so in every place in `scss` file where I need to use `@media` query, I can use it in the following way:

```
@media #{$mobile}  {
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Is it possible to use in the same way `$mobile` variable with [styled-componenents](https://styled-components.com/)?

I have tried to export this variable like I do with other sass variables:

```
:root {
  --c-global-red: #{$c-global-red};
  --mobile: #{$mobile};
}
```

Now if I need to use for example `$c-global-red` in **styled-component**, I can do it as following:

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
    color: var(--c-global-red);
`
```

Can I use same approach to use `--mobile` variable with `@media` tag?
Something like this:

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
    color: var(--c-global-red);
    @media var(--mobile) {
        color: blue;
    }
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can reference global CSS variables within a styled-component, you can't reference sass variables nor global CSS variables containing strings. Instead, you'll want to leverage the [ThemeProvider](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#themeprovider) with theme variables.

---

#### Demo

Within the Codesandbox editor, adjust the middle scrollbar by moving it left and right to see changes in the `Button`.

[image: Edit Styled-Component Global Vars]

The reason this works is because `theme.mobile` is interpolated to `"(min-width: 320px) and (max-width:479px)"` when the styles are created:

```css
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:479px) { ... }
```

Whereas, `var(--example)` is just interpolated to the string `"var(--example)"`, which is invalid [CSS syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries):

```css
@media var(--mobile) { ... }
```

On that note, this may or may be considered anti-pattern since you're reliant upon global CSS variables within a global CSS stylesheet. You can completely avoid using CSS by just using [theme variables](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming).

---

#### Code

**App.js**

```
import { ThemeProvider, css } from "styled-components";
import Button from "./Button";
import "./styles.css";

const theme = {
  mobile: "(min-width: 320px) and (max-width:479px)"
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Button>No Theme</Button>
      <br />
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Button>With Theme</Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Button.js**

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = styled.button`
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--white);
  background: var(--blue);
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;

  :hover {
    background: var(--darkblue);
  }
  
  ${({ theme }) =>
          `@media ${theme.mobile} {
          ${css`
             background: var(--pink);

            :hover {
              background: var(--darkpink);
            }
          `}
    }`}
`;

export default Button;
```

**styles.css**

```css
.app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --blue: #1e87f0;
  --darkblue: #0f7ae5;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --pink: #ff93ac;
  --darkpink: #ff6289;
}
```