# How do I use CSS env variables in media query width values?

Tags: css, environment-variables, media-queries, css-variables

```css
@media screen and (max-width: env(--width-max)) {
  .foo {
    font-size: var(--fonts-size);
  }
}

:root {
  --width-max: 0;
  --fonts-size: 1rem;
}
```

As I understand it, the above code should set a media query on the `.foo` element, however it is not being picked up by the browser. I saw the postcss-media-variables library, but would prefer to use `env`, but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. How can I access CSS env variables in a media query?

Comment: I don't believe variables are supported in media queries at this time.

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries

Comment: @NathanielFlick That answer only says to use `env()` but not how. @brewster is already trying to use `env()` but it's not working. The real question is how do you SET an `env()` variable, which I cannot find explained anywhere either.