# Global scss variables not behaving as expected

Tags: sass

I have a scss file that I `@import "./global-style/scss-variables";` in index.scss, with the following content:

```
:root {
  --spacing: 8px;
  --iphonewidth: 375px;
}
```

When I call a variable in the scss of one of my components, like `margin-bottom: calc(#{var(--spacing)} * 2);`, 8px is inserted in the `var(--spacing)` placeholder. However, `var(--iphonewidth)` is not 375px as would've been expected, which is used here:

```
@media screen and (max-width: var(--iphonewidth)) {
    ....
}
```

I'm not sure why variables in sass behave this way. Maybe because variables may not be used in media queries?

Comment: CSS variables are resolved at runtime, SCSS variables are resolved at compile time, string interpolation in SCSS `#{...}`is resolved at compile time (everything SCSS is compile time). So what does `#{var(--spacing)}` yield? Simple. The string `var(--spacing)` and that is inserted in `calc( __here__ * 2 )` and that will work during runtime. But your second use case is not supported, see this [question and the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries).

Comment: Ah okay, that explains. Only after posting this question it came to mind that maybe it has to do with the media query, hence my edit lol. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

For SCSS:

```
$spacing: 8px;
$iphonewidth: 375px;


.selector {
    margin-bottom: calc( #{$spacing * 2} );
}
```

For CSS:

```
:root {
  --spacing: 8px;
  --iphonewidth: 375px;
}

.selector {
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--spacing) * 2);
}
```

Comment: This works, but variables are not global in this example.

Comment: Hi @DSteman, I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: That is not explaining the observed bahavior.