# How can I pass css variable to media queries in Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, media-queries

I want to pass css variable into my media query but I don't know how.

It's a Next.Js project, and I use `theme-ui`'s `sx` property to assign style.

```
const styles = {

    headerLinkContainer: {
        width: '500px',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        alignItems: 'center',
        "@media screen and (min-width: var(--medium-devices))": {
            display: 'none',
        }
    },
}
```

I tried `"@media screen and (min-width: 'var(--medium-devices)')"` but it doesn't work.

Can you help me guys ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use media queries in js.
The best solution is this:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Also I found an answer here if someone needs it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries