# Combine SCSS @custom-media queries in one definition

Tags: css

I have several custom-media query definitions set up, things like:

```
@custom-media --mobile (width < 535px);
@custom-media --tablet (801px <= width < 1025px);
@custom-media --desktop (width >= 1025px);
...
```

In which I use like:

```
@media (--mobile) {
    // Some mobile styles here
}
```

I know that we can perform a combination of media queries with the `and` join like:

```
@media (min-width: 30em) and (orientation: landscape) { ...
```

Is there any way in which I can define a media query that utilises 2 of my custom-media variables, to have a certain style like:

```
@media (--mobile) and (--desktop) {
    // Styles that only apply at mobile and desktop sizes
}
```

Comment: You can't use *CSS custom properties* in a `@media` declaration. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723269/7100628).

Comment: This question seems to be about the PostCSS Custom Media plugin, not SCSS.