# pass global value css in @media

Tags: css, media-queries

any body know if it's possible to pass value global from `:root file` to other `css file` for `@media operation`. I've the feeling is not possible.
If it's possible, how ?
If it's not possible, why ?

my idea is do that

global css file loaded at first

```css
:root {
 --value: 200px;
 --my-height:20px;
}
```

other css file

```css
@media(min-width : var(--value)) {
 .my_class {
   height: var(--my-height);

}
```

Comment: According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723269/9288348 it is not possible. However it is possible to rewrite your ```:root{...}``` variables inside your @media

Comment: a good resource about that: https://bholmes.dev/blog/alternative-to-css-variable-media-queries/

Comment: The variables can be read in the second file but "you just cannot use them in a media query declaration"