# Why can't I change the background colour with html selector with this media query?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```css
html, .large { font-size: 36px;
     color: #ffffff;
     background-color: #000000; 
} 
               
/* This does not work @media(max-width: 600px) { html { background-color: lightblue; } */               
@media(max-width: 600px) { 
  body { background-color: lightblue; }  
}  
             

blockquote, button, select, .bq, .required {
background-color: #0d0d0d; 
    color: #ffffff;      
    font-size: 0.8rem; 
}

ul { text-align: left }

ul li { display: inline; 
        font-size: 62.5%;
        margin:  50px;
        padding: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="large">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="myBlogDM.css"/>
   <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://english-writing.github.io">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="samples.html">Sample CVs</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog/1.html">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/">Twitter</a></li>
  <li><a href="faq.html" >Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>                      
                           
  <h1>Jim Smith</h1>
 <hr>
  <h3>Writer</h3>
   <p>I write CVs and letters in English in html and pdf. 
I am an experienced writer ... 
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

As the comment points out, when I use `@media(max-width: 600px) html { background-color: lightblue; } }`
it does not change the background colour in response to the resizing of the browser window or
the opening of the file on a mobile device. Yet, when I change the selector to `body`
than it works as intended.

```
When I my stylesheet to html { font-size: 36px;
     color: #ffffff;
     background-color: #000000; 
}
```

then it works, why?

If the background colour of my document was set with `html` selector
in the first place, why doesn't it change with
`@media(max-width: 600px) html { background-color: lightblue; } }`?

Comment: Have you tried html, body?

Comment: @VictorPieper With `html, body` it works. Why doesn't it work with `html` only?

Comment: Have you tried `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`? This looks like a typo to me, though I don't have any means to check right now, unfortunately.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have, it does not work.

Comment: @JohnSmith I believe you have a mistake in your css example it now says /* This does not work */  on your working code (:

Comment: PRobably your body doesn't match the html height. I tested your snippet in full page and resize it i'll see body background change but it doens't fit the html height

Comment: @JohnSmith I just tested this in a snippet, if you chance your body to html it does work.

Comment: @JohnSmith Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries

Comment: @VictorPieper Not sure if it does becasue I'm not using `:root` but `html` selector instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the CSS specification on [*Background of Special Elements*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds):

> For documents whose root element is an HTML `HTML` element or
> an XHTML `html` element: if the computed value of `background-image` on the
> root element is `none` and its `background-color` is `transparent`,
> user agents must instead **propagate** the computed values of **the
> background properties from** that element’s first **HTML `BODY`** or
> XHTML `body` child element.

That means the background properties of `BODY` only propagate to `HTML` if `background-image` and `background-color` of `HTML` are `none` and `transparent` respectively, which they are by default.

```css
html {background-color: red}
body {background-color: blue} /*Won't propagate!*/
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    Some content
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
/*No background properties on HTML set.*/
body {background-color: blue} /*Will propagate.*/
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    Some content
  </body>
</html>
```

This is why the document's `background-color` will remain `black` (or `#000000`) in your example, even after setting `BODY`'s `background-color` to `lightblue`.

Another reason why your declaration doesn't work is [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). You select the `HTML` element with both its type and its class, which results in the selectors' specificity being `0-0-1` and `0-1-0`, respectively.

You select `html` in the media query, which has the specificity of `0-0-1` and is therefore *less specific* than the selector `.large` with a specificity of `0-1-0`: Declarations of selector `.large` override declarations of selector `html` in the media query.

For default/initial declarations you may want to wrap your selectors in the [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) pseudo-class function to reduce their specificity to `0-0-0`.