# Change sass variable value based on media query

Tags: css, sass

I use `$section-padding: 32px;` to set paddings on multiple elements such as

```
body {
    padding: $section-padding;
}

.section-title {
    width: calc(100% - #{$section-padding *2});
}

.site-footer {
    padding: 60px 0 $section-padding;
}
```

Now I need to adjust that value when using media queries so instead of updating all of the styles, I would just like to adjust the value of $section-padding for example

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
    $section-padding: 16px;
}
```

I've added to my sass

```
$section-padding: 32px;
$section-padding-lg: 16px;
$section-padding-md: 8px;
$section-padding-md: 4px;
```

But then I'll still have to update all of the styles everywhere it's used.

Comment: Does a native CSS variable suit your needs?

Comment: Yes, I considered that and I might have to go that route but I'm trying to avoid having to update all my code.

Comment: Add a `--section-padding: 32px;` to `:root`, mirror it using a `$section-padding`, then modify it in the media query. How does that sound? If it works for you I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @InSync you should post that as an answer, since it's a great solution and then I won't post the same answer. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS native variables not working in media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries) Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723076/1172189

Comment: @disinfor Oh well, too bad :P

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to achieve only with SASS variables because `@media` rule is read by the browser and SASS code is generated before serving it to the browser.

You can compare SASS variables with CSS variables to achieve this:

```
:root {
  --section-padding: 32px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
    :root {
      --section-padding: 16px;
    }
}

$section-padding: var(--section-padding);

body {
    padding: $section-padding;
}

.section-title {
    width: calc(100% - ($section-padding * 2));
}

.site-footer {
    padding: 60px 0 $section-padding;
}
```

Comment: As @InSync suggested I'll give this a go.

Comment: This is giving me an error when using such as ```padding: ($section-padding * 2);``` Undefined operation: "var(--section-padding) times 2".

Comment: @Junky I updated my answer, I changed this SASS calculation to standard CSS `calc` only