Calc not working with media queries and neither are variables
Using bootstrap 5.3.1
Trying to write a media query that changes things as the page size shrinks from bootstrap-lg (e.g. min-size = 992px) into a medium sized page ( e.g. max size = 991px wide)
This works.
@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
    #home-page__content-outer{
    padding-left:0;
    }

    #home-page__hero-banner .hero__title p{
        font-size:65px;
    }

}

BS defines --bs-breakpoint-lg : 992px
This doesn't work
@media screen and (max-width: calc( var( --bs-brekapoint-lg) - 1px)){
    #home-page__content-outer{
    padding-left:0;
    }

    #home-page__hero-banner .hero__title p{
        font-size:65px;
    }

}

If I define a new variable: --bs-breakpoint-below-lg : 991px
and change my media query to the below it also fails
@media screen and (max-width: var(--bs-breakpoint-below-lg)){
    #home-page__content-outer{
    padding-left:0;
    }

    #home-page__hero-banner .hero__title p{
        font-size:65px;
    }

}

if I delete var(--bs-breakpoint-below-lg)  and replace it with 991px  it works again so its not the query.
I've checked in my styles and the definitions are in the browser. It just seems media queries don't work with variables or calculations.
From the stylesheet seen in Firefox on the rendered page in the :root section
    --bs-breakpoint-below-sm: 575px;
    --bs-breakpoint-below-md: 767px;
    --bs-breakpoint-below-lg: 991px;
    --bs-breakpoint-below-xl: 1199px;
    --bs-breakpoint-below-xxl: 1399px


I'm using FireFox 124.0.2

Does this answer your question? CSS native variables not working in media queries

This article covers the issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries?rq=2]
Basically a media query is a GET ( ie get max-width ) not a set e.g.
width: 991px;

