property "color-scheme" cannot query by media "prefers-color-scheme"
I learned that "color-scheme" property can change the light dark mode of the page. And I also learned that i can style element by media query prefers-color-scheme from MDN. But actually, it doesn't work for me.
My code is like this:
:root {
  color-scheme: dark;
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  body {
    background-color: var(--theme-color-extreme-light);
    color: var(--theme-color-extreme-dark);
  }
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: var(--theme-color-extreme-dark);
    color: var(--theme-color-extreme-light);
  }
}

But it doesn't work as expected. I want to know if there is a misunderstood in color-scheme property.

This looks like a CSS variable issue to me. Yep - Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries

@Paulie_D Not related to CSS variables, if you replace them with static color values, it still doesn't work as expected.
